# ios Product Page Optimization stopped

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ab-testing, abtest

I am using Product Page Optimization for the first time. i updated the new version of the app and the test stopped. There is no button to reactivate the test. Status header says developer has stopped, but I didn't stop it. how can i restart this test?

[image]

star button not showing

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Product Page Optimization is based on the current released version of your app.

According to [this page](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devdfd4ac235) of Apple, submitting a new app version for review "automatically stops any tests that are in progress".

To restart your test, you must create a new test.